# CertificateException when calling JAX-RS web service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jax-rs, weblogic12c

I have a JAX-RS web service running in WebLogic 12.2.1. I am able to use a browser to call the service with either HTTP and HTTPS. Since the SSL certificate is self-signed, I have to trust it when prompted in the browser.

In a test standalone program (important part shown below), I can also call the service with HTTP, providing the IP address of the server in the URL.

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5320/MLM").build());
Invocation.Builder builder = target.path("Services/Init").request();
Response response = builder.get();
String responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

However, when I change the URL (changed the port and IP address to host name) in the client code to the HTTPS one, I got the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
```

The common name in the certificate is the same as host name of the server. I can also ping the host name from where the client program is run. The client program is run with the below JVM arguments, which I specify the keystore file storing the SSL certificate.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mlm-sit.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxx
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e5140). Try and configure the client with SSL

Comment: Thanks peeskillet. That link is useful. The root cause of my problem is that I didn't restart the server when I changed the keystore. The original certificate has a Common Name that did not match the host name of the server. So I had to change to a new certificate and keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created a new keystore for the server with a new Common Name, but I did not re-start the server. So what happened was that the old Common name was used, which did not match the actual host name of the server. I just need to re-start the server, and the problem is resolved.